# How to render mod_articles_category using custom php code?

Tags: module, joomla-3.6, module-display

I am writing PHP API for Joomla3.9  website where I need to deliver the HTML produced by mod_articles_category modules. 
I tried blow code to get Module HTML output but it does not working any more
It shoiwng the erro someting like that  "Call to a member function get() on null"

```
define('_JEXEC', 1); 
include_once DIR . '/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php'; 
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php'; 
$app      = JFactory::getApplication('site');

jimport('joomla.application.module.helper'); 

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module'); 
$module   = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_articles_category', 'Module title I used here'); 

echo $renderer->render($module); 

?>
```

Basically  I need this module HTML  output in the same way as it render on Joomla pages so that I can send this out to REST API user. It showi

Please suggest me

Comment: Please describe exactly how it _doesn't work anymore_. This is essential in a complete question.  Are you seeing errors? Blank screen? Mangled output?  Some volunteers will already know, but it makes your question higher value to express what isn't working properly.

Comment: This is my complete php code
define('_JEXEC', 1);

  include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');

$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_articles_category', 'Module title I used here');
echo $renderer->render($module);

?>

Comment: It showing not a blank page only

Comment: Please edit your question, then delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JModuleHelper::renderModule($module)`  instead of `$renderer->render($module)` also add code in your question along with the value of $module object, so we can understand your issue better and provide solutions accordingly.

Comment: I tried your code  it showing error 
Call to a member function getTag() on null

Comment: Your API called for this code is directed from controller or accessing a file directly?  As you are loading the framework. 
If you are redirected from the controller framework will be included already, in your case you will not be receiving any value in the $module, it may be due to the framework or any dependent file not included properly.